# make httppost in android properly

Tags: php, android, http-post

I'm trying to make an android app which communicates with a php file/database.
I don't get it working, I'm completely new at this kind of android programming.
I already got this from a tutorial:

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
 name = userInput.getText().toString();
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com/register.php");
 try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }


}
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
// including database connection
$name= $_POST['name'];

$register= "INSERT INTO Users (Name, Level) VALUES(".$name.", 1)"; 
$result   = $conn->prepare($register);
$result->execute();
```

When I startup my app it instantly crashes.
What I'm doing wrong?
Does this code still work?
Did i forgot something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42386056/7320259 check my answer

Comment: Share your logcat

Comment: where to find logcat?

Answer (score 0):

> When I startup my app it instantly crashes.

You should call http requests in a background thread. You can use AsyncTask for that purpose.

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com/register.php");
 try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", params[0]));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

You can run it using `new LongOperation().execute(userinputString1);`

Comment: U have some examples on how to do that?

Comment: you need to import android.os.AsyncTask;

Comment: where to add my user input?

Comment: Thanks but it still says cannot resolve symbol execute

Comment: @Rewtie sorry, i forgot something..  use this line. new LongOperation().execute(userinputString1);

Comment: Ok the app still crashes, can i give you my full code in PM or something??

Comment: Any ideas on how to find whats going wrong with my app?

Comment: email me : rewtie12@gmail.com to get things working and so we can connect and give data to eachother

Answer (score 0):

All database communication should be done in the background. This can be done by using an AsyncTask or an other Worker. Also you need the Internet permission, add this line to the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

But I'd recommend you to use a library like Retrofit for API calls. This spares you pain in the ass, and with the combination of GSON it is very powerfull.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Google `AsynchTask` in Android and learn what it is. And keep in mind all network related operations has to been done in a separate thread instead in the main android UI thread. So the code you are trying should be look like this

```
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
 name = userInput.getText().toString();
 new CallPostService().execute();
}

class CallPostService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.test.com/register.php");
 try {
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

       progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

And remember to add the below line in manifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code, it will help you
 https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask