# php cannot read uft8 json

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8

I am now writing Android apps and the apps will use json(utf8):

`http://.....xxx.php?json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22peterchan%22%2C%22phone%22%3A%2212345678%22%2C%22password%22%3A%226kxhSJM6iLB0kZ9LZGCEUQ%3S%3D%0A%22%7D`

the `xxx.php` is like:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
    ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
    $json = $_GET["json"];
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $name = $obj -> {"name"};
    $phone = $obj -> {"phone"};
    $password = $obj -> {"password"};
    printf($json);
?>
```

but it returns:
`Warning: printf()`: Too few arguments in `xxx.php`

Can anyone help me? Please

Comment: You should use `POST` if you want to create something...and `GET` just for retrieval...

Comment: may I have some examples? for android
I cannot find a work example with "put" JsonObject

Comment: what do you need to use `printf()`?

Comment: after I got the json
I will inset the data into mysql DB

Comment: `PUT` should make a full update on your data. Here is a `POST` example

Comment: sorry, where has an example?

Comment: I have tried to use similar to the following code, it post to mysql
but still return empty
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114698/send-a-json-object-from-android-to-php-server-with-post-method-and-httpurlconnec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should validate `json_decode` doesn't return `null` and check for errors if so using [`json_last_error_msg`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Your password ends with a newline (maybe it shouldn't be there), which is [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%0A` which is invalid because [in JSON newlines must be escaped as `\n`](http://json.org/) which would be percent-encoded as `%5Cn`

demo: https://3v4l.org/vTM2r

```
$broke = '%7B%22name%22%3A%22peterchan%22%2C%22phone%22%3A%2212345678%22%2C%22password%22%3A%226kxhSJM6iLB0kZ9LZGCEUQ%3S%3D%0A%22%7D';
$fixed = '%7B%22name%22%3A%22peterchan%22%2C%22phone%22%3A%2212345678%22%2C%22password%22%3A%226kxhSJM6iLB0kZ9LZGCEUQ%3S%3D%5Cn%22%7D';

var_dump(urldecode($broke));
// string(80) "{"name":"peterchan","phone":"12345678","password":"6kxhSJM6iLB0kZ9LZGCEUQ%3S=
// "}"

var_dump(json_decode(urldecode($broke)));
// NULL

var_dump(urldecode($fixed));
// string(81) "{"name":"peterchan","phone":"12345678","password":"6kxhSJM6iLB0kZ9LZGCEUQ%3S=\n"}"

var_dump(json_decode(urldecode($fixed)));
// object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
//   ["name"]=>
//   string(9) "peterchan"
//   ["phone"]=>
//   string(8) "12345678"
//   ["password"]=>
//   string(27) "6kxhSJM6iLB0kZ9LZGCEUQ%3S=
// "
// }
```